# Android - how to handle locale class

Tags: android

In android My requirement is :--
when my app will open,there will be a spinner..this spinner will call locale languages..user can set own language from there..And then total app(other activities) will show as user's select language.

so my code is like:--

```
String lang[] = locale.getISO3Language();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,lang);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {

        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    }
```

Am I correct??or is there another efficient way????pls suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is not necessary, as the app determines on runtime which language to use (the one the user chose in device settings). Just put a folder for each language you support into the res/ folder and specify a strings.xml file there.

The default file is in folder values/ (used, e.g. if you do not support the user's language). Just add a folder named values-es/ for spanish, values-fr for french etc....

Spanish, /values-es/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

French, /values-fr/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mon Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Bonjour le monde !</string>
</resources>
```

See Google tutorial: (That's where I stole the code, too ;-))

[Supporting different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Comment: That means  have to create "strings.xml" for every country and for every activity???????? is there any simple way??

Comment: Yes, you need to create a "strings.xml" for every country. But there is no need to create one for every activity. Each activity can access the same "strings.xml".

Answer (score 0):

This link maybe helpful, please go through it:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: It is considered good form to write a simple answer here and then refer to the documentation